# How to Make TamperMonkey Script Work on chrome-extension:// Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

So this seems like it should be really simple, but I can't find it anywhere on Google. I have a certain Google Chrome extension that I've downloaded from the Chrome Extension store, and I'm trying to slightly tweak the way it displays some stuff on its chrome-extension:// page. TamperMonkey normally works great for this on a http:// page, but I can't seem to get my script to even activate for a chrome-extension:// page. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: This is not possible.  Google explicitly codes against this. Perhaps the Vivaldi browser might one day support it (doubtful).  You can also fork the Chromium project and add/restore this capability (not a quick prospect).

Comment: Gotcha, so maybe I could accomplish this by creating a separate extension that uses chrome.extension.getViews() to modify this extension's page? Or would that not work either?

Comment: Won't work.  But keep trying and let us know if you find something.  Many of those pages need a good scripting.

Comment: @Timothy, any news about the progress and success of your development?

Comment: I'm interested in this too. I know that Brave browser has flags "Enable extension network blocking" and "Extensions on chrome:// URLs" that could help this